# No more links and anchors when merging two pdfs

Tags: itext7

We created an app using iText 7.1.0 and html2pdf 2.0.0 to build our pdfs.
In our first iteration we send one data-object to it which includes html for header, body and footer, in addition meta-data like title etc is included.

The html-body included 2 parts: details-part and a table-part.

Everything worked fine so far, the links and anchors were styled and clickable, meta-data is set correctly (Beside this: we have still a problem in our header html, there is a logo placed but we are not able to build a link around this).

We changed the behavoir of the app: now we put a collection of data-objects to the app (details-part and table-part separated; each of both data-objects include html for header, body and footer, also meta-data). We iterate over the collection, use the same method which worked fine before and merge the two parts together.

Now the links and anchors are styled but not clickable anymore. Also we see no meta-data. Did we something wrong when building the merge?

The controller:

```
public byte[] index(@RequestBody PDFDataModelCollection elements, Model model) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
    try (PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
        for (PDFDataModel pdfDataModel : elements.getElements()) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(creationService.createDatasheet(pdfDataModel)));
            try (PdfDocument sourceDoc = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
                int n = sourceDoc.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                    PdfPage page = sourceDoc.getPage(i).copyTo(resultDoc);
                    resultDoc.addPage(page);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

The method createDatasheet():

```
public byte[] createDatasheet(PDFDataModel pdfDataModel) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);

    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

    try (
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc)
    ) {
        document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        //meta tags
        PDFMetaService.addPdfMetaTags(pdfDoc, pdfDataModel.getMetaModel());

        Header header = new Header(document, this.fontProvider, pdfDataModel.getHeader());

        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, header);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.INSERT_PAGE, header);

        Footer footer = new Footer(document, this.fontProvider, pdfDataModel.getFooter());
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.INSERT_PAGE, footer);

        //watermark
        PDFImageModel pdfImageModel = pdfDataModel.getImageModel();
        if (pdfImageModel != null) {
            Watermark watermark = new Watermark(document, pdfImageModel);
            pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, watermark);
        }

        //body
        for (IElement element : HtmlConverter.convertToElements(pdfDataModel.getBody(), this.props)) {
            document.add((IBlockElement) element);
        }

        footer.writeTotalNumberOnPages(pdfDoc);
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

The pdfDataModel.getMetaModel(), pdfDataModel.getHeader(), pdfDataModel.getBody(), etc. are returning setter/getter classes; there the html is stored.

Any suggestions would be helpful...

Comment: Please attach examples of files that produce the issue as well as a self-reproducible code example. In your current code there are some unclear external dependencies.

Comment: I'm afraif, I'm not allowed. I'll edit my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've changed the controller to this and it works now:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public byte[] index(@RequestBody PDFDataModelCollection pdfDataCollection, Model model) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);

    try (PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
        LOGGER.debug("Parsing {} element(s) from PDFDataModelCollection.", pdfDataCollection.getElements().size());
        for (PDFDataModel pdfDataModel : pdfDataCollection.getElements()) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(creationService.createDatasheet(pdfDataModel)));
            PdfDocument sourceDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
            sourceDoc.copyPagesTo(1, sourceDoc.getNumberOfPages(), resultDoc, resultDoc.getNumberOfPages()+1);
        }

        PDFMetaService.addPdfMetaTags(resultDoc, pdfDataCollection.getElements().get(1).getMetaModel());
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```